# Rewrite Rules are not working for CMS Page URL

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, cms-pages

I have added new Rewrite Rules for two CMS pages to redirect from one to other,
For Example:

In Marketing > Seo-Search > URL Rewtite added one rule:
/shipping  to /shippment

But still not redirecting to it, Also run the indexing cache flushed, but success.

I am Using NGNIX by the way no Apache, is there any special changes to made?